# Trying to get my string to rotate left. What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: java, string

I am new to Java and am trying to get my code to work and am a bit stuck. I want to have a string rotate a random amount to the left, but I keep running into errors. Here is what I have currently:

```
String rotateLeft(String input, int i) {
  if (input == null) {
    return null;
  }
  if (input.length() == 0) {
    return input;
  }
  int r = i % input.length();
  String one = input.substring(input.length() - r);
  String two = input.substring(0, input.length() - r);
  return one + two;
}
```

If I could get some help fixing it that would be amazing!

Edit: I changed my code around a bit and this is now what it looks like:

```
// String Rotate Left
String rotateLeft(String s, int rotate) {
  // Sanity checks
  char[] rotatedString = new char[s.length()];
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    int newPosition = (i + rotate) % s.length();
    assert newPosition >= 0 && newPosition < s.length() : "Bad index " + newPosition;
    rotatedString[newPosition] = s.charAt(i);
  }
  return new String(rotatedString);
}
System.out.println(rotateLeft("CS125", 1));
```

Instead of it printing out S125C, it prints out 5CS12. How would I change it to print out what I want?

Comment: It will be helpful if you post your code rather than sharing images? You can paste your code surrounded by ```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

To carry out a rotate to the left on a string, one way to do it is indeed with a concatenation of two sub-strings from the supplied input string basically just like you are using but you've over complicated it:

```
String leftRotatedString = input.substring(numberOfCharsToRotate) 
                         + input.substring(0, numberOfCharsToRotate);
```

I can't for the life of me however see how there is anything in your code that is random. If you want to rotate by a random number of string characters then perhaps utilize the **[Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)** class along with its **[nextInt()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/random_nextint_inc_exc.htm)** method, for example:

```
// The input string:
String input = "MississippiRiver";

// Generate a random 'index' value of the input string:
int rnd = new Random().nextInt(input.length() - 1) + 1;

// Carry out the rotation:
String leftRotation = input.substring(rnd) + input.substring(0, rnd);

// Display the random rotation value (the number of characters to rotate left by): 
System.out.println("Random Number Of Characters To Rotate By: -->  " + rnd);

// Display the rotated result string:
System.out.println("Result: -->  " + leftRotation);
```

**EDIT: Based on your posted Edit update:**

You would do a right rotation instead, for example:

```
System.out.println(s.substring(s.length() - 2) 
                 + s.substring(0, s.length() - 2));
```

The output will be:

```
5CS12
```

Comment: I made some changes to my code that are shown above! Sorry I couldn't figure out how to show the changes down here!

Comment: @Kaimera, See Edit update in answer above.